# Android How to Catch end of call with type of call and number?

Tags: android, service, listener

could somebody give me example or link with:

How to Catch end of call with type of call (outgoing, incoming) and numbers of callers (number which was called or number which was received)?

Thanks for any advice.

Edit:

Permissions are foolowing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

receiver is defined by this way:

```
<!-- RECEIVER FOR WATCHING INCOMMING AND OUTGOING CALLS -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="2">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

On receive:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        String incomingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); //store incoming number
        String outgoingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


        if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
        {
            Log.i("TEST","Outgoing " + outgoingPhoneNumber);
            Log.i("TEST","Incoming" + incomingPhoneNumber);

        } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
            Log.i("TEST","Offhooked");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For incoming call -
You can use `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` intent in broadcast receiver to catch end of incoming call like below -

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
      if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
       { number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.i("incoming", ""+number);
       Toast.makeText(context, ""+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
          { outgoingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
       Log.i("outgoing", ""+outgoingPhoneNumber);
        // Toast.makeText(context, ""+outgoingPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
        {   
            //Do whatever you like

        }   

}
```

and the below code

```
if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
            {   
            Log.i("TEST","Outgoing " + outgoingPhoneNumber);
            Log.i("TEST","Incoming" + incomingPhoneNumber);

            }
```

will always return null because whenever state changes onReceive will be called again and at that moment the number will be null. So if you want to access the number after call has ended,store it using shared preferences and retrieve later on in `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`

You can find a well written tutorial here - [Call Detection](http://androidlabs.org/short-experiments/broadcast-receivers/do-something-when-the-phone-rings/)

Comment: TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER and Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER returns null. How can i solve it?

Comment: have you declared the receiver in the manifest ? with proper permissions ?

Comment: Strange.. i am using the same code and its working fine. Can you post your onReceive method code

Comment: I finally resolved using separated receivers more in this article:
http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/android-broadcastreceiver-tutorial-detect-outgoing-phone-call-event/